# NSLOOKUP is Not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu

I had provided FQDN of the server in host file and did all the necessary changes even after i am getting error on ubuntu 12.04
i am executing command

```
nslookup hadoopmaster.impps.co.in

Server:         172.26.32.7
Address:        172.26.32.7#53 
** server can't find hadoopmaster.impps.co.in: NXDOMAIN
```

and hostname -f command is giving output

```
hadoopmaster.impps.co.in
```

Comment: maybe more of a question for http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: Does your DNS server know about this host?

Comment: @stijn not sure have to check for that. How do i?

Comment: @msturdy i have no idea about serverfault.com..

Comment: @VikasHardia sister site of this one, thought that you might get a better response there, this site is aimed more at specific programming questions!  :)

Comment: @VikasHardia Then you're probably in over your head here. Anyway, I've voted to close as off-topic. http://superuser.com might be able to help you, but don't quote me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we need to add entry in DNS about the host.

Nslookup skips the hosts file and queries DNS server for FQDN if DNS finds any entry associated with name he returns the IP Address of the server.

you can find the IP of the DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf on your system.